# How can I define global block then render inside twig?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

Is it possible to set global block for twig file, so that I can access that block inside twig.

For example, I want to have **{% block currency %}${% endblock %}** this block as global block, then I want render this block in all other twigs like, **{{ block('currency') }}**.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to create the twig containing that block and then add that file in config.yml

```
# app/config/config.yml
twig:
    form_themes:
        - 'form/fields.html.twig'
```

You can see an example in [cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#making-application-wide-customizations)